# Migrating from Struts 2.3.x to Struts 2.5

Tags: struts

We a few legacy apps that are on Struts 2.3.x, which is EOL now and we are looking to upgrade:

Questions:

1)     Any pointers to migration guide from Struts 2.3.x to Struts 2.5.x?

2)     Has anyone here has gone thru the efforts of migrating from Struts 2.3.x to Struts 2.5.x? what challenges did they come across and the solutions that helped them overcome those challenges?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are only 3 steps to do that
1. change you dependency in pom.xml of struts from 2.3.x to 2.5.x
2. Change the top tag in struts.xml from 2.3.x to 2.5.x
3. import struts-2.5.dtd instead of 2.3.dtd

You dont have to make any specific change since there is not a big difference between struts2.3 and 2.5

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changes in Aakashdeep Singh's answer, The StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter was moved from org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter to org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.

You may want to refer the [migration guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration) provided by Struts to ensure you don't miss anything.

Comment: move to comments